# Getting a StorageException (403: Forbidden) on CloudStorageContainer GetContainerReference method

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm running the following code in a unit test against Azure's Storage Emulator and receiving a StorageException when I attempt to create the container:

```
var connectionString = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==";
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("my-container");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

The Storage Emulator is running and the Blob service is supposedly running at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:10000/
```

The exception is:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException : The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Any thoughts?  Is this possible from a unit test?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please change your connection string from:

```
var connectionString = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==";
```

to

```
var connectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
```

That should take care of the problem you're facing.

Comment: In case someone else looks at this, an authentication error can be miss-leading. In my I case I was getting getting this kind of error due to using a backslash rather than a forward slash.

Comment: Under SDK 2.2, that connection string returns a 400 (Bad Request) error.  Is that supposed to work with 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

```
container.SetPermissions(
                    new BlobContainerPermissions
                    {
                        PublicAccess =
                            BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                    });
```

When initialize connection.
But first, use a Client for Storage and change permission of container using the Client.

Works for me ;)