# Can't create azure blob container on storage emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm unable to create a container while using Azure Storage Emulator from my c# .NET code.

I am using:

```
var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("media");
container.CreateIfNotExists();`
```

It return the error Error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: What is your connectionstring?

Comment: See whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265483/azure-storage-emulator-blob-creation-gives-403-forbidden-message?answertab=votes#tab-top) helps.

Comment: Yes this worked! I was using only the account name and the key value. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line:

```
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

This will let the application use the credentials of the logged in user to access the site. If it's returning 403, clearly it's expecting authentication.

It's also possible that you (now?) have an authenticating proxy in between you and the remote site. In which case, try:

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

You could set a connection string to the [storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) in an app.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
</appSettings>
```

If you want to connect to storage emulator using account name and key, you would need to provide additional details like different endpoints.

```
var connectionString = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
    BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;
    TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;
    QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;";
```

This value is identical to the shortcut shown above, `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`.

Comment: Yes it's working with the additional details. Thanks! :)